# UIScrollView is glitchy and shaky when scrolls to the top

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uiscrollview, autolayout

I have a `UIViewController` that contains a `UICollectionView` and a `UIView` which acts as the view header.

I would like to collapse the header when the view scrolls. I am currently doing this by capturing the top anchor for my header in a variable and using `scrollViewDidScroll` to set the `constant` for this value.

```swift
  func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    headerTopAnchor.constant = max(-headerView.frame.height, -scrollView.contentOffset.y)
  }
```

This works, as the collection view scrolls up the header scrolls off screen and vice versa.

However, in the event that the content in the collection view does not *quite* fit - if there is only half a cell or so that scrolls off screen, there is a weird shuddering behaviour.

If I add a print statement to `scrollViewDidScroll` I can see the collection view is over scrolling by a small amount and this causing the top anchor to change multiple times by a small amount

```swift
  func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    print(max(-headerView.frame.height, -scrollView.contentOffset.y))
    headerTopAnchor.constant = max(-headerView.frame.height, -scrollView.contentOffset.y)
  }
```

How Can I prevent this behaviour?

I have included a view controller that should demonstrate the problem -

```swift
final class TestViewController: UIViewController {

  private let headerView: UIView = {
    let view = UIView(frame: .zero)
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.backgroundColor = .systemTeal
    return view
  }()

  private(set) lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
    collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    collectionView.backgroundColor = .clear
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "UICollectionViewCell")
    return collectionView
  }()

  private lazy var headerTopAnchor = NSLayoutConstraint()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = .systemGray
    [headerView, collectionView].forEach(view.addSubview(_:))
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
      headerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
      headerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
      headerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 180),

      collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerView.bottomAnchor),
      collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
      collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
      collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor)
    ])

    headerTopAnchor = headerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor)
    headerTopAnchor.isActive = true
  }
}

extension TestViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // return 300 // no problem
    return 10 // problem :(
  }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "UICollectionViewCell", for: indexPath)
    cell.backgroundColor = indexPath.item % 2 == 0 ? .darkGray : .lightGray
    return cell
  }
}

extension TestViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
  func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    print(max(-headerView.frame.height, -scrollView.contentOffset.y))
    headerTopAnchor.constant = max(-headerView.frame.height, -scrollView.contentOffset.y)
  }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return .init(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: 60)
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using a section header? It will operate like all other cells but is detached from the normal cellForItem and sizeForItem functions so you have control over it specifically. It will also appear at the top of the collection view. I think this may be your intended operation and would probably be the recommended approach if so. Otherwise, I believe the error is coming from the `headerTopAnchor.constant = max(-headerView.frame.height, -scrollView.contentOffset.y)`

Comment: Hope my answer addresses the problem that you're facing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like `UIScrollView` has a `bounces` property which is set to `true` by default.

From the documentation:

> If the value of this property is true, the scroll view bounces when it
> encounters a boundary of the content. Bouncing visually indicates that
> scrolling has reached an edge of the content. If the value is false,
> scrolling stops immediately at the content boundary without bouncing.
> The default value is true.

This explains that shuddering behaviour where the animation is being applied whilst being corrected by your top constraint while hitting the boundary.

I set `collectionView.bounces = false` in `viewDidLoad` and it works like intended now.